# Assigning a jsp variable a value based on HTML selection list

Tags: jsp

```
<%String m="1"; %>
```

In my JSP file

```
<select name ="test">
   <option value="2"> 2 </option>
   <option value="3"> 3 </option>
   <option value="4"> 4 </option>
</select>
```

Based on what is chosen on selection list I want to assign value to the variable m. What is the best approach to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a HTML `<form>` and add a submit button.

```
<form>
    <select name="test">
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="3">3</option> <!-- Why 2 same options? -->
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This way the variable will be sent as HTTP request parameter with the name of the input element as parameter name. You can then get it as follows:

```
String m = request.getParameter("test");
// ...
```

Note that postprocessing a form submit is normally to be done in a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), not a JSP.